# Node.js server file download via external link

Tags: node.js, express, file

I 'm trying node.js server (Express.js) to download file via external link. But connection is closed when file is not fully downloaded. So the file size is 0byte.

```
// Express.js route

axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `externalLink`,
  responseType: 'stream',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  },
})
  .then(function(response) {
     res.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-Type': EXCEL_MIME_TYPE,
       'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + response.headers['content-disposition'],
       'Content-Length': response.data.length,
     })

     res.end(Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'))
  })
```

the result is 0kb excel file.
When console.log on then block, content length is 0.

But if I download the file via browser, then the file download is successful. In Chrome inspect, the file's Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

I think connection is closed before full byte is transferred to node.js server. How can I transfer external link file via node.js server?

Thank you.